# How to best friction fit/join two tubes with identical diameters?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aluminum, joining

I have a number of tubes in a thin aluminum that are identical with each having one side that ends in a hemisphere shape and the other with a cap shape.  I'm trying to find more information about trying to friction join the cap ends without the caps together to make a shape that would appear to be an elongated pill capsule.

I've been able to do this before, but I seem to have either misplaced or just lost the files about the project and have (so far) been unable to find information on Google, other SEs, etc., though that may just because I'm not using the optimal search terms.

**My question is does anyone know how this might be done?**  The most obvious solution would seem to be to slightly deform one side's diameter to be a little more narrow than the other and then slide them together.  If anyone could point me in the right direction for more information about this sort of technique or concept I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: it would be easier to expand one

Comment: a diagram would help.  "Cap" shape is not a standard term I'm familiar with.

Comment: Swage on end to make it larger.